# Why does this function returns twice the result?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, plugins, jquery-plugins

I got a simple question. Why does this function returns twice the width of **only the first element** if the function holds a resize function?

```
var $element1 = $( '.one' ),
    $element2 = $( '.two' );

function Width( element ) {
    $( window ).resize(function() {
        var width = element.width();
        console.log( width );
    });
    $( window ).resize();
}

Width( $element1 );
Width( $element2 );
```

Is it something wrong with my code?

fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/eLLcZ/

fiddle without the resize function http://jsfiddle.net/VbX8L/

Comment: `$( window ).resize();` triggers all handlers for the event. Not just those added for an individual `element`.

Comment: Yes but **separately**. It will returns the width of *$element1* and *$element2*. But when I do this in a resize function it will return twice the width of *$element1* and just one time the width of *$element2*.

Comment: They're not actually separate since the events are bound to `window`. Each call to `Width()` only adds 1 handler, but then triggers all of the `resize` handlers that the `window` has accumulated thus far. So, `Width($element2);` triggers the event for `$element1` again as well as its own.

Answer (score 2):

Using `$( window ).resize();` within `Width()` will invoke all of the `window`'s accumulated `resize` handlers each time:

```
Width( $element1 ); // the `window` has 1 `resize` handler, it's invoked
                    // log: 100

Width( $element2 ); // the `window` has 2 `resize` handlers, both are invoked
                    // calling the 1st handler a 2nd time (totaling 3 logs)
                    // log: 100
                    // log: 150
```

This expansion would continue if you had additional elements (e.g. `$element3` at `200px`):

```
Width( $element3 ); // Adds a 3rd handler, invokes the 1st and 2nd again
                    // log: 100
                    // log: 150
                    // log: 200
```

---

To only invoke the current handler, at least at the time when it's being bound to the event, you'll want to call it directly rather than triggering the entire event each time:

```
function Width( element ) {
    function onResize() {
        var width = element.width();
        console.log( width );
    }
    $( window ).resize(onResize); // add for later
    onResize();                   // call once now
}

Width( $element1 ); // log: 100
Width( $element2 ); // log: 150
```

You can still trigger the entire event later to run through all of the handlers at once:

```
$( window ).resize(); // log: 100
                      // log: 150
```

Comment: so basically if later on I will can again another $( window ).resize(); nothing will work?